# Jboss AS7 server Jconsole.bat

Tags: caching, jboss, jboss7.x, jmx, infinispan

I tried to access mbeans on a remotely running Jboss AS7 infinispan server using the jconsole.bat from the infinispan Jboss AS7 installation and i am gettign the following error:

```
xception in thread "VMPanel.connect" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnectorProvider.<clinit>(RemotingConnectorProvider.java:42)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.Service$LazyIterator.next(Service.java:270)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.getConnectorAsService(JMXConnectorFactory.java:425)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:310)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:247)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:207)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:336)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:296)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:280)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 11 more
```

I used both url's : service:jmx:remoting-jmx://:9999
                    service:jmx:remoting-jmx://:4447

CLASSPATH:

```
    C:\Developer\JDK\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib\jconsole.jar;C:\Developer\JDK\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib\tools.jar;C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1-bin\infini
span-server-6.0.0.CR1\jboss-modules.jar;C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1-bin\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\
remoting-jmx\main\remoting-jmx-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1-bin\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1\modules\system\layers\base\org
\jboss\staxmapper\main\staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1-bin\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1\modules\system\layers\base\
org\jboss\as\protocol\main\jboss-as-protocol-7.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1-bin\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1\modules\system\l
ayers\base\org\jboss\dmr\main\jboss-dmr-1.1.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1-bin\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1\modules\system\layers
\base\org\jboss\as\controller-client\main\jboss-as-controller-client-7.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\infinispan-server-6.0.0.CR1-bin\infinispan-server-6.
0.0.CR1\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\threads\main\jboss-threads-2.1.0.Fin
```

Comment: What Infinispan Server version?

Comment: I Added the classpath from my jconsole.bat

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine at hand now, but I tried with a *nix environment and the script we have and it seems to work fine. I guess the Windows version might be outdated. I'd suggest opening a JIRA [here](http://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN) with the information that you have so that we get it fixed.

Comment: Hi Galder i created the following JIRA:ISPN-3707